# Sqlite, DataGridViews and BindingLists

Tags: c#, sqlite, bindinglist

I have been able to successfully create, deploy, read from and write to a SQLite DB.
Now I am wanting to take a query (`SELECT * FROM Device`) and return the result into a BindingList to be able to use it in a DataGridView. I can do it with a List, but as it's a list I can't seem to be able to delete rows in the DGV. Attempting to do so gives the error: "Rows cannot be programmatically removed unless the DataGridView is data-bound to an IBindingList that supports change notification and allows deletion."

Ok Fine. So how do I return the query result into a BindingList?

Here is the code to put the results of the query into a List:

```
public static List<DeviceModel> LoadDevice()
        {
            using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
                {
                    var output = cnn.Query<DeviceModel>("SELECT * FROM Device", new DynamicParameters());
                    return output.ToList();
                }
        }
```

And here is the code to remove an item:

```
private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DeviceModel p = new DeviceModel();
            SqliteDataAccess.RemoveDevice(p);


            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.InventoryTable.SelectedRows)
            {
                InventoryTable.Rows.RemoveAt(InventoryTable.SelectedRows[0].Index);
            }
            InventoryTable.Refresh();
        }
```

I feel that it's something silly that I'm missing.
Thanks!

Comment: Note that the error message quoted says rows cannot be ***removed*** which is different than *deleting* and indeed, `RemoveAt` removes from that object, and does not delete from the database.  There is no real reason you must use a `List` or a `BindingList` as a `DataTable` will work fine.  When the user presses delete the row is marked for deletion and when you update the DB, it is then deleted.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp So I should then be able to just delete the row from the DB, then refresh, without having to actually remove the row from the DGV?

Comment: If you or the user **deletes** the row from the `DataTable` it is then and there instantly removed from view and queued for deletion. Using  `myDataAdapater.Update()` updates the database and physically deletes the row.  No need for a "refresh" except under certain situations.  Basic DB Ops are very simple and easy once you learn the capabilities provided